# Bootstrap container conflict with css footer menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a website that has footer menu. And i'm using `container` in my content since i don't know how to make it center. When I tried to apply the footer menu without using `container`. The `background-color` of the footer expand upward where the last `div` without container. And the text won't center.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyMZi.png)

It become like this when I use `.mainbar:float:left;` and `.sidebar:float:right;`

HTML

```
    <div class="container" id="content">
      <div class="mainbar">
         <img src="img/img2.png"><br>
            <h4>Sample text.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
         <a href="#"><img src="img/banner.png"></a><br>
         <a href="#"><img src="img/banner.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>


<footer>
        <div id="fnav"">
            <ul>
                <li class="fmenu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="fmenu-item"><a href="#">会社情報</a></li>
                <li class="fmenu-item"><a href="#">製品情報</a></li>
                <li class="fmenu-item"><a href="#">採用情報</a></li>
                <li class="fmenu-item"><a href="#">お知らせ</a></li>
                <li class="fmenu-item"><a href="#">サポート</a></li>
                <li class="fmenu-item"><a href="#">お問い合わせ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
                COPYRIGHT © SAMPLE Template .ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
        </div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
#content .mainbar{
            float: left;
            width: 736px;
}
.sidebar{
        float: right;
        width: 214px;
}
#fnav{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}    
#fnav ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
 }    
 #fnav ul li.fmenu-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}    
#fnav ul li.fmenu-item a{
    color: #262d33;
    text-decoration: none;
}    
.copyright{
    font-size:10px;
    color:#444;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this style too, which resolve your problem.

```
footer {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

hope this is help you `footer` style

```
footer {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working but I use `float: left;` because the menu will move to right and it won't be center.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use Float if you are using Bootstrap 4. Please check below example maybe it's helps you.

```css
.content-bar {
  min-height: 450px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.side-bar {
  min-height: 450px;
  background: #eee; 
}
footer {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
            <div class="content-bar">
              Mainbar
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="side-bar">
              Sidebar
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
      Footer
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```